# Creating new Application using Node and Angular for Auto login --- Need Insights

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, nightmare

I have an application to create using Nodejs as backend, Angularjs  as frontend and MySQL for backend.

The aim is that on search page which is opened on user's browser, I must show the user all the links from different websites when he clicks search button and when the user clicks on a link listed in this search, he will be auto logged in that website's homepage in a new popup  (I will already have his credentials for these websites).

How do I send cookie (the authentication of specific website) from node to user's browser.

Server to server login and authentication.

OR is there any other way to approach this functionality. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Cookies are private between the browser and the site the cookie is for.

A third party site can't read or write cookies belonging to a different site. That would be a security problem.

Comment: can we use virtual browser to login via node server in a website and store cookie and send the same page(with all elements) to user and record user actions and send it back to node server for further processing.

Comment: Yes, you could write a proxy server.